# Why is my imageview transparent/not showing properly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am really confused about this.I have set the background color of the whole screen to blue and I have a framelyout with image view under it. When I choose playingcard drawable as its source then the white background of the playing card is becoming blue and the image is not clear. Why is this happening? 
Below is what the screen is looking like:

[image: This is what is looking like].

My image is :

:[image]

And here is Part of the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0000FF" >

   <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/frameLayoutBottom"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/ivBottom2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:src="@drawable/c11"/>
```

I don't want to set the background of image to white as I am using padding and I don't want the padding to be white.. The weird thing is that if I use other images that are say red then it shows perfectly, it is just when I use playing cards (I have 52 cards), it is showing like that
Any help please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image has transparent pixels. Use an image editor to convert them to white.

Alternatively, you can [specify a margin](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) instead of padding and [setBackgroundColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) on your ImageView.